# Variable has incomplete type 'QPrinter'

Tags: ios, objective-c, qt, qprinter

I am trying to use QT in iOS.

```
#include <QtGui/qprinter.h>

QPrinter print;
```

Above code gives "Variable has incomplete type 'QPrinter'" error. Though QtGui/qprinter.h has complete definition for QPrinter. Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Comment: what is the QPrinter? is it an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `qprinter.h` file has this preprocessor condition before the definition of `QPrinter`:

```
#ifndef QT_NO_PRINTER

// class QPrinter {
// ...
// }

#endif
```

Maybe on iOS `QT_NO_PRINTER` is defined, perhaps because it is not supported? I can't find any official documentation that says as much, but it would be easy enough to test if that macro is defined in your build.

Comment: I figured QT_NO_PRINTER was defined. Thanks for all the help!